# What do you call a person living in a safe house?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What would you call the person that lives in a safe house, to save them from a much worse situation, say a person seeking freedom, escaping violence. The text I am translating refers to the African Americans who were offered a place in Underground Railroad safe houses during the period of slavery in the US.

I'm looking for a generic word (not the official "freedom seekers" or similar) - something that has to do with them being "protected" (a synonym for "protectee")
The sample sentence is:

> The comforter on the bed has star and moon patterns...  Mother didn’t make it herself...  it was a gift from one of her ***poor protectees*** when we arrived here. It was a gift from Mrs Dillard, as thanks for the help she’d received.

Comment: Not sure if this is good enough for an answer but a **refugee** is someone who has sought **refuge** which is what a **safe house** is. A **refugee** is usually considered to be someone who has fled their country, but the situation fits the question, and literally means someone in a refuge.

Comment: ***Safe***, one would hope.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, refugee is along the right lines, it's a noun so fits the grammar of the sentence, but it's quite a loaded word (especially nowadays) and I think I need something more neutral, that would also fit the historical time period - mid 19th century America (Boston).

Comment: Hello M.T., and thank you for posting on EL&U. While your question is very interesting, we have several requirements for posts. From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.  "

Comment: "Refugee" is the only word I can think of, but it is almost always associated with someone who has fled to a different country. Failing that the word is usually qualified in some way e.g. "refugees from the front line", "refugee from justice" (negative connotation) etc.

Comment: I'm sorry if I haven't posted this question properly.. it's my first time. I was just looking for one word that fits the meaning I tried to provide, without dragging in other languages etc.  The sample sentence is: The comforter on the bed has star and moon patterns <snip> Mother didn’t make it herself <snip> it was a gift from one of her poor protectees when we arrived here.  It was a gift from Mrs Dillard, as thanks for the help she’d received.

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question in hope that it might express your intent more clearly. If you are unhappy with the changes, you may at any time choose to "roll back". Once again, thank you for visiting.

Comment: I initially thought of ***ward***, but that is usually reserved for children. However, if context is already clear, you can simply call the person a ***resident***.

Comment: _Shelterer_ is used in [some books](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1745&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=koNvXKvnG6rGjwSoxZm4Ag&q=%22shelterers%22&oq=%22shelterers%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5118.5118.0.5223.1.1.0.0.0.0.64.64.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.xuhW97UvEII) about London underground shelters in WW2 era and other topics. It is not a common word and it can also mean one who shelters another.

Comment: shelterer  is great!!!! the word choice in my original text is not common either. Thanks.

Comment: Why is "protectee" not sufficient? If you want a generic word in a context where it's already understood you're talking about a safe house you could say "resident".

Answer (score 1):

There are several candidates that fit particular circumstances within your general definition: *refugee*, *runaway*, *outcast*, *fugitive*.

> *refugee* = a person who leaves his or her home or country to find safety, esp. during a war or for political or religious reasons
>
> *outcast* = a person who is not accepted or has no place in society or in a particular group
>
> *runaway* = someone who has escaped or run away from somewhere
>
> *fugitive* = a person who is running away or hiding from the police or a dangerous situation
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fugitive)

Of these, I suggest *fugitive* as the most general meaning, encompassing all the others. Any of the others may be a fugitive.

Comment: **Fugitive** is supported by "She Came to Slay: The Life and Times of Harriet Tubman" By Erica Armstrong Dunbar https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o920DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=harriet+Tubman&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib5c73r_j2AhXEiVwKHTneCb8Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=harriet%20Tubman&f=false

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest they are "under protection" or "taking refuge", but if you need a single-word noun perhaps "refuge-takers" would work?

Comment: yes, the "poor people under her protection" I was thinking.. although it's a bit longer that the "poor protectees" which would the literal translation of what I'm translating from.

Comment: @MagicamenteTranslations If you are doing a _translation_, you need to provide us with the original text. Some of us here actually have a few languages between us and may be able to provide a better translation: however, in this case i doubt it. It is curious that you are doing a translation INTO English, unless it is from an African language. Is this for ONU, or USAID?

Comment: it's literature and it's from IT: povere protette. I didn't mention it because I was thinking more of a word search to find something suitable..equivalent in English rather than a translation. The author is using a generic term, the reader is supposed to understand what she is implying, but without her saying it explicitly (fugitives/escapees/freedom seekers/runaway slaves), perhaps it's the sensitive way they referred to the people who passed through their house.

Comment: OK @MagicamenteTranslations We have several REALLY good polyglots here, and I have no doubt that they should be able to assist you..however, [povere protette] should be included in the question...however...once again, why is this coming from IT into  AmE.?

Comment: I am not well versed in the historical details of the time, buu is it posible that the host referred to the people as *guests*. I suppose that reflects a 21st century sensibility and trend to destigmatize people one is tryng to help.

Comment: Replying to Cascabel: why not? It's a piece of narrative, non-fiction for children, being brought into English. I am only trying to find the correct word for the context.